# Setting Background color in CSS with Dreamweaver

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I am trying to add a background to my webpage by using a cascading style sheet in Dream Weaver CS5. I was fortunate enough to find this code:

```
html, body {height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

#full-screen-background-image {z-index: -999; min-height: 100%; min-width: 1024px; width: 100%; height: auto; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;}

#wrapper {position: relative; width: 800px; min-height: 400px; margin: 100px auto; color: #333;}
```

Which is added to the style sheet, and this bit:

```
<body>
  <img alt="full screen background image" src="/background.jpg" id="full-screen-background-image" /> 
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p>Content goes here...</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

which is added to the HTML.

However whenever I try to add another element to the page, such as an image or text, the image appears directly below the background which I have set as if the code in the style sheet does not set a background at all.

Could someone possibly tell me what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use `background-image: url('background.jpg');` in the `body` CSS or in `#wrapper`?

Comment: The problem with background-image is that background-size is not widely supported yet. I assume he wants a full-screen stretched image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's actually working fine because `position:fixed;` pulls the image out of the flow of the page. I think your culprit is actually the `margin: 100px auto;` rule on `#wrapper`.

I played with your CSS a bit and cleaned it up. Is this the desired outcome?

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMzEw/)

```
html, 
body {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}

#full-screen-background-image {
    z-index: -999; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:#F00;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative; 
    width: 800px; 
    /*margin: 100px auto; */
    color: #333;
}
```

Alternatively if you don't need background scaling/stretching, you can use this:

```
body {
    background-image: url(/background.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Nice, I could kick myself! So it would seem that when viewed in dreamweavers design view the added elements aren't able to be displayed as a part of the page! Insanity Thanks for the fresh perspective. I appreciate it. :) You saved a life. :)

Comment: Not sure, I haven't used Dreamweaver in like 10 years :P Remember to press the tick to accept the answer if it's resolved the issue.